# How to convert an Adobe Illustrator file to only one colour?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to generate a new IcoMoon font by uploading this .ai image to IcoMoon.

[a simple .ai file](https://gofile.io/?c=IMQ893)

However, once I upload the image and generate the font.
IcoMoon generates a multicolor font:

[image]

But I don't want to generate a Multicolor font. 
IcoMoon shows the solution and says that:

[image]

Now I have Adobe Illustrator, but how can I change all colours in the .ai file to a single colour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i checked the file you uploaded and you have multiple layers on top of each other, [image]

what you can do is delete the excess layers then add the color you want and export it as svg

Comment: Thanks, this works. However, is it ok if I just remove those excess layers? I'm wondering why those layers are there? Wouldn't be a risk that removing the excess layers reduces the thickness of the font?

Comment: i don't know the exact reason but it happens sometimes when you use shape builder tool and no it will not affect the thickness of the font